# Slave caching server is not available

Tags: c#, redis

Have anyone experienced the following error when trying to fetch data using [csredis](https://github.com/ctstone/csredis) SDK:

```
Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.EnsureNotClosed()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at CSRedis.Internal.RedisWriter.Write(RedisCommand command, Stream stream)
   at CSRedis.Internal.RedisConnector.Call[T](RedisCommand`1 command)
   at CSRedis.RedisClient.Write[T](RedisCommand`1 command)
   at CSRedis.RedisClient.Get(String key)
```

What could be the reason? Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you attempt to fetch the data?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Basically using the `string CSRedis.IRedisClient.Get(string key)` method.